# Would this be on topic: "What practical advantages should I expect from ECC memory?"

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm wondering whether this will be on topic. I read the Help page, and a few Meta pages, but I'm not sure.

> I'm considering building a Xeon/ECC computer, because ECC sounds
> attractive: no errors! Perfection! Borg! The computer is intended to
> be a general-purpose computer, used for gaming, Photoshop, having 200
> browser tabs open, running a virtual machine or two, etc. It's
> supposed to be future proof, as far as medium-budget builds go.
>
> Most people say ECC memory has no effect on gaming. That seems
> reasonable. And I think I have the disadvantages down: more expensive,
> less compatible, lower frequency. But **what positive effect from ECC
> memory *can* I expect in practice, on a general-purpose computer?**
> Fewer programme crashes? Fewer occurrences of those odd little things
> one half-notices on one's computer as one is performing general tasks?
> Or what else?
>
> [This page](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Advantages-of-ECC-Memory-520/) talks about the advantages and disadvatages of ECC
> memory extensively. But I'm having trouble translating what they say
> into practical computer use. For instance, better system stability:
> does that mean fewer blue screens? But I never have blue screens
> anyway. Fewer odd hiccups?

If it should be off topic, do you happen to have a suggestion for a place where I could ask this and get reasonable answers?

Answer (score 1):

This would be off topic, but thanks for asking.

Questions on HR are expected to ask for the recommendation of a single specific piece of hardware. Technical support and general advice type questions are out of scope; I'm not sure which one of these categories the question would fall under, but I think it would fall into at least one.

If you need technical assistance, Super User might be your best bet (always read the help centre or ask on mets, as you have, before asking). There aren't very many hardware sites on the network at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm OK, thanks for your answer. I'll try Super User then, I guess. How about if I wanted to ask a question like this: "I want to use SK Hynix DDR4 memory, because that is supposed to be somewhat immune to row hammer. Is that true? This is my build: ... What RAM do you recommend?" Would that be on topic?

Comment: @Cerberus in theory yes, as long as you've got specific requirements in mind for it. There should be some guidelines among the [meta-tag:faq] tag here on meta.